# Custom Setting in VfP - PE

Tags: visualforce, customsetting

I'm trying to create a PDF which should give out the value of a specific custom setting. Tried this with very little hope, it won't render:

```
<apex:repeat var="muster" value="{!$Setup.Musterhaus__c}">
  <apex:PageBlock rendered="{!If(Lead.Musterh_user__c == muster.Name__c, true, false)}">
    <p class="smallText">
      {!muster.Name__c}
    </p>
  </apex:PageBlock>
</apex:repeat>
```

Does anybody have an Idea how I'm able to show fields of a custom setting in a VfP, only when the name equals a field of Object X?

Cheers, Tim

Comment: is your custom setting hierarchy or list type.. if list then use like this http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/04/how-to-display-custom-setting-data.html   .. AS documentation says `$Setup to access hierarchical custom settings and their field values using dot notation.`  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_setup.htm

Comment: I'm working in a PE so I can't work with Apex / edit the controller. I have to work VfP only.

Comment: Professional Edition

Comment: You are directly working in production environment.  I suggest first develop this in sandbox and then deploy the page and controller to production..

Comment: Which should not make a difference the PE has no access to apex which would mean no extensions or custom controllers either. I'm not seeing how this would affect the development.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `apex:repeat` so I hope it is list type of custom setting. In that case query this custom setting record and store it in list in controlller and then display it in your VF page.

```
<apex:repeat var="muster" value="{!cusSettList}">
  <apex:PageBlock rendered="{!If(Lead.Musterh_user__c == muster.Name__c, true, false)}">
    <p class="smallText">
      {!muster.Name__c}
    </p>
  </apex:PageBlock>
</apex:repeat>
```

This will solve your problem.

You can use [`Map<String, CustomSetting__c> getAll()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) to get the record. You don't need to query this as well.

Comment: I don't have Apex, sorry for not clarifying further, working in a PE.